# How to change the home page in grails?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm using the plugin on my project "spring-security-core: 2.0-RC2". Through the "s2-quickstart" command I created the USER and ROLE domains. When running the project, it created the screen, where I can test the login. 
How do I get this screen is the first to be called?

PS: I don't created the controller and view because the plugin does this automatically creates.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home page is whatever "/" is mapped to in `UrlMappings.groovy`. If the login screen is rendered by the `login` action of `UserController`, set the following in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/"(controller: "user", action: "login")
```

Alternatively, if the GSP that creates the login screen can be rendered directly (i.e. does not require a model), set the following in `UrlMappings.groovy`

```
"/"(view: "/login")
```

The above assumed that the login screen's GSP is at `/grails-app/views/login.gsp`